# Python Django: Remove null=true from Model CharField

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Unfortunately I have a large model in production (Django 2.0.5) defined with `null=True` on CharFields:

```
class FooterMenu(models.Model):
    text_de = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Menüpunkt (de)", max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    text_en = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Menüpunkt (en)", max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    text_fr = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Menüpunkt (fr)", max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

Unfortunately there are plenty of NULL Values in the postgres DB already.

If I just remove the `null=True` and `makemigrations` the `migrate` tells me: `cannot ALTER TABLE "doctor_footermenu" because it has pending trigger events`

I understand this happens because of the NULL values in the table.

Is there a proven strategy that I can use?

Comment: As you said, you are getting this error because you want to set a field to NOT NULL while it has NULL data records. You first need to change existing NULL values to a default string. If you are working on local database, then you can simply open django shell and update the null values. If you are looking for something more professional, you should write a django migration to update the NULL values.

Comment: I see. Using `RunSQL` in `operation` ?

Comment: You can use either [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) or [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) . For this case, i would choose RunPython since ORM supports the query you will write, you should choose RunSQL for advanced queries that ORM does not support.